# How to re-render the DOM quickest in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am Trying to move a text across the screen on a fixed amount of time and for that I have come up with the following code

```
import React, { Component, useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { PrismCode } from "react-prism";
import { Player, ControlBar } from "video-react";
import { Button } from "reactstrap";
import { getSub_Millis } from "../../services/srtreader";

export default function Rythmoband(props) {
  const initialPosition = useRef(
    props.rythmoPosition === undefined ? "30%" : props.rythmoPosition
  );

  const [number, setnumber] = useState(
    props.dialogueNumber === undefined ? 0 : props.dialogueNumber
  );
  const [timerCheck, setTimerCheck] = useState(true);
  const [moverNumber, setMoverNumber] = useState(0.001);
  const [currentTime, setCurrentTime] = useState(0);

  const textMover = () => {
    let x = parseFloat(initialPosition.current);
    let start = getSub_Millis(props.time[number][0]);
    let end = getSub_Millis(props.time[number][1]);

    let timeToMove = start - end;
    setMoverNumber((timeToMove / 2500) * props.player.playbackRate);

    setCurrentTime(props.time.currentTime);
    x = x + moverNumber;
    let y = `${x}%`;
    initialPosition.current = y;
  };
  setTimeout(() => {
    textMover();
    timercheck();
    backChecker();
  }, 0.1);
  const timercheck = () => {
    if (
      getSub_Millis(props.time[number][1]) - props.player.currentTime * 1000 <
      1
    ) {
      initialPosition.current = "30%";
      setnumber(number + 1);
    }
  };
  const backChecker = () => {
    for (let index = 0; index < props.time.length; index++) {
      if (
        getSub_Millis(props.time[index][1]) > props.player.currentTime * 1000 &&
        getSub_Millis(props.time[index][0]) < props.player.currentTime * 1000
      ) {
        setnumber(index);
      }
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div
        style={{
          width: window.innerWidth,
          background: "#FF8232",
          marginTop: "20px",
          height: "75px",
          position: "relative",
          border: "5px solid black",
        }}
      >
        <div
          style={{
            width: "5px",
            background: "red",
            marginTop: "20px",
            height: "75px",
            position: "absolute",
            top: "-25%",
            left: "25%",
          }}
        ></div>

        <strong
          style={{
            position: "absolute",
            left: initialPosition.current,
            top: "25%",
            fontSize: "2rem",
          }}
        >
          {props.dialogue[number]}
        </strong>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

In the above code setTimeout is responsible for calling the same functions repeatedly after a set time which in turn moves the text across the screen in a calculated manner. Now the problem is that the text element's movement is blocky rather then smooth although I have tried altering the time intervals and the movement speeds as well. I would appreciate if some one could help me figure out a better way to make the text move smoother.

Comment: I recommend using [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) instead of [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout).
There is a little utility hook that you could use to re-render your component: https://github.com/streamich/react-use/blob/master/docs/useRaf.md

Answer (score 1):

1. For performance, avoid updating state everytime
2. The setTimeout accepts milliseconds, means 0.1milliseconds is very hard for performance, maybe 0.1 seconds.
3. There are lot of animation packages on React, this one is very mechanic
4. The solution: Use css transition instead

Comment: You are right about the transition thing but how am I supposed to calculate how the css transition moves